# What does _app.js and _document.js file do? What's "_" (Underscore) for in next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

When I created a next.js app using `npx create-next-app` there is 2 js files named app and document leading with an **Underscore** what is that for?

The files are like this:

```
▼ pages
  _app.js
  _document.js
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a matter of convention. `_` indicates that the file is partial and not supposed to be exposed as a page to the user.

Here is a quote from one of the contributors of Next.js.

> We actually use the underscore (_) prefix for 'private' (internal, but not actually secret) pages, based on common convention of underscores often being used to denote that.

[Source](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/8454#issuecomment-530815768)

Answer (score 0):

By naming these files with an underscore prefix, Next.js indicates that they are special files that should not be directly accessed by the user. Instead, they are meant to be used as templates or boilerplate codes that can be modified to fit the specific needs of your application.

Comment: Can you extend your explaination, or refer to some resource(s) ?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).